# 3gp video format viewable in Picasa/Flickr/Facebook?

Tags: facebook, flickr, picasa-web-albums

Is the 3gp video format viewable in a simple browser once uploaded to Picasa or Flickr or Facebook?

If not, what is the best format to transform it to so that it can be viewed in all of these 3 sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3gp is a common shared between the 3 services you asked for.
The only limit you have is on Flickr where the video must be shorter than 90 seconds, so only 1 minute and 30 seconds long for this service.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, specially useful to know the limits of Flickr.